# Trigonometric substitution : $a^2-x^2$ why substitute : $x = a \sin t$

Tags: integration

On the wikipedia page of trigonometric substitution it says :

Substitution 1. If the integrand contains $a^2 − x^2$, let : $x = a \sin t$.

And my question is : Why not substitute : $x = a\cos t$ ?

Comment: That would probably also be fine. Try it out next time you run into such a substitution!

Comment: I would try not to re-use $x$ this way. It should be $x=a\sin t$.

Comment: It works out just the same.

Comment: Ok, because everyone seems to teach the substitution : $ x = a\sin t$

Comment: I think to avoid potential negatives, people typically teach these substitutions without using the co functions. $\sin, \sec, \tan$ are easy to work with and give you a potential list of three rather than six, which is great for new learners. But as long as you understand the process, anything is allowed.

Comment: Ok, interesting to know !

Answer (score 1):

You can use $x=a\cos{t}$ instead of $x=a\sin{t}$ for $a^2-x^2$, but we usually use $x=a\sin{t}$ because using $x=a\cos{t}$ introduces a negative sign when differentiating because if $x=a\cos{t}$, then $dx=-a\sin{t}\,dt$. Similar things will happen if you use cotangent for $a^2+x^2$ and cosecant for $x^2-a^2$, since they also have negative derivatives.